# Zip file help Final Core

Tags: zip

I downloaded a game called Final Core and it is a zip file that I don't know how to open.
if anybody knows please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GUI of Nautilius, simply double-click. It may ask you to install some packages, but it will guide you through that.

In the console, make sure you have the `zip` package installed. (Try running `zip`)

If it works:

1. `cd /path/to/the/zip/`
2. `mkdir extract` (OPTIONAL, BUT RECOMMENDED)
3. `mv file.zip extract/` (OPTIONAL, BUT RECOMMENDED) (Needed if above was run)
4. `cd extract/` (OPTIONAL, BUT RECOMMENDED) (Needed if above was run)
5. `unzip file.zip`
6. Open Nautilus/whatever and browse to that folder
7. ???
8. Profit.

If `zip` DOESN'T work:

1. `sudo apt-get install zip`
2. Proceed from steps above, or Nautilus.